# data-ng-enter bypasses client side validations

Tags: angularjs, client-side-validation

```
<form name="Form" class="form" data-ng-enter="saveInfo()" novalidate>
<div class="question-group">
    <label class="question" for="FirstName">
        Your first name*
    <input id="FirstName" type="text" data-ng-model="app.FirstName" maxlength="40" required />
    </label>
    <label class="question" for="LastName">
        Last name*
    <input id="LastName" type="text" data-ng-model="app.LastName" maxlength="80" required />
    </label>
</div>

<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 155px;" class="button-center">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-ng-click="saveInfo()" data-ng-disabled="Form.$invalid">
        Save
    </button>
</div>
```

I am disabling the save button if the form fails client side validations but when I hit enter in the input field it bypasses the client side validations and submits the form. I don't want that to happen. I want to submit the application when I hit enter if and only if it passes all the client side validations.

Is there any way to check if the button is disabled then data-ng-enter shouldn't work something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `data-ng-submit` instead of `data-ng-enter`

Comment: Is there any way to display some message  to the user as data-ng-submit doesn't do anything or show my client side validation messages to the user when I hit enter.